# Algoritmo de Astar excede el límite de tiempo

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, rendimiento

Tengo un código que reduce la lista hasta que todos los elementos restantes sean iguales. Toma una primera línea que contiene un número entero n, el número de elementos en la lista, y una segunda línea que contiene números enteros separados por el espacio. Por ejemplo, con la entrada de la muestra:

```
5
3 3 2 1 3
```

Debería regresar 2.

Como se veía como un gráfico orientado, implementé Astar:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

class Node:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.value = len(set(arr))
        self.arr = arr
        self.parent = None
        self.H = 0
        self.G = 0

def children(arr):
    s = list(set(arr))
    children = []
    for deleted_element in s:
        arr_copy = list(arr)
        arr_copy.remove(deleted_element)
        child = Node(arr_copy)
        children.append(child)
    return children
    # return [Node([x for x in arr if x!= deleted_element]) for deleted_element in s] # issue


def astar(start, goal):
    # the open and closed sets
    openset = []
    closedset = []
    # current point is the starting point
    current = start
    #add the starting point to the openset
    openset.append(current)
    # while the openset is not empty
    while openset:
        current = min(openset, key=lambda o:o.G + o.H)
        # if it is the item we want retrace the path and return it
        if len(set(current.arr)) == goal:
            print("inside, current.arr: " + str(current.arr))
            path = []
            while current.parent:
                print("path in while: " + str([x.arr for x in path]))
                path.append(current)
                current = current.parent
            print("path: " + str([x.arr for x in path]))
            path.append(current)
            print("path: " + str([x.arr for x in path]))
            return path[::-1]
        # remove the item from the openset
        openset.remove(current)
        # add it to the closed set
        closedset.append(current)
        # loop through the node's children and siblings
        print("current.arr: " + str(current.arr))
        for node in children(current.arr):
            #If it is already in the closed set, skip it
            if node in closedset:
                continue
            #Otherwise if it is already in the open set
            if node in openset:
                # check if we beat the G score
                new_g = current.G + 1
                if node.G > new_g:
                    # if so, update the node to have a new parrent
                    node.G = new_G
                    node.parent = current

            else:
                # if it isn't in the openset, calculate the G and H score for the node
                node.G = current.G
                node.H = len(set(current.arr))
                #Set the parent to our current item
                node.parent = current
                #add it to the set
                openset.append(node)
    # thow an error if path is not found
    raise ValueError('No Path Found')

# Complete the equalizeArray function below.
def equalizeArray(arr):
    startNode = Node(arr)
    path = astar(startNode,1)
    path.pop(-1)
    print("path: " + str(path))
    return len(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    result = equalizeArray(arr)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Funciona, pero para algunos arreglos toma demasiado tiempo comparado con el tiempo que tengo cinco. No soy capaz de encontrar cuál es el umbral a partir del cual mi algoritmo, pero lo hace para ejemplos como:

```
78
24 29 70 43 12 27 29 24 41 12 41 43 24 70 24 100 41 43 43 100 29 70 100 43 41 27 70 70 59 41 24 24 29 43 24 27 70 24 27 70 24 70 27 24 43 27 100 41 12 70 43 70 62 12 59 29 62 41 100 43 43 59 59 70 12 27 43 43 27 27 27 24 43 43 62 43 70 29
```

Entonces, ¿cómo puedo mejorarlo? *Dale a un hombre un pescado, y lo alimentarás por un día. Enseña a un hombre a pescar, y lo alimentarás toda la vida*. Estoy ansioso por aprender y mejorar mis habilidades de programación. Estoy abierto a cualquier consejo e intento pedagógico para convertirme en un mejor programador. ¡Así que no dudes en darme una lección!

Comment: ¿Cual matriz? No veo ninguna matriz. De acuerdo con la Wikipedia, "Typical implementations of A* use a priority queue".

Comment: @CandidMoe la lista! Me disculpe, Estoy cansado.

Comment: No entendi el primer ejemplo. ¿Qué es 2? ¿Indice, posición en la lista, valor del elemento? ¿Cual es la lista reducida?

Comment: @CandidMoe Me disculpe, No me he explicado bien. 2 es, en el caso `3 3 2 1 3`, el nombre de iteraciones minimal hasta que todos los elementos restantes sean iguales. Es la lista `3 3 3`

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar cuales son las acciones válidas?, es decir, si estoy en un estado N, ¿qué acciones puedo aplicar a ese estado que me terminen generando un nuevo hijo?. Algunas posibles preguntas que debería responder la definición de las acciones validas podrían ser: ¿Es válida la acción de eliminar elementos de la mitad de la lista?, ¿La única acción válida es eliminar elementos en los extremos de la lista?, ¿Una acción puede eliminar más de un elemento en un solo movimiento o cúal es el máximo?

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta ni el ejemplo que pones con una lista que se reduce a un numero, ni que relacion guarda todo ello con el algoritmo A*. Editala y explicala mejor cuando estés descansado ;-)

Answer (score -1):

El enunciado del problema no guarda relación con el código publicado.

Formalmente dices *Tengo un código que reduce la lista hasta que todos los elementos restantes sean iguales*.

Aqui está la lista:

```
x = "24 29 70 43 12 27 29 24 41 12 41 43 24 70 24 100 41 43 43 100 29 70 100 43 41 27 70 70 59 41 24 24 29 43 24 27 70 24 27 70 24 70 27 24 43 27 100 41 12 70 43 70 62 12 59 29 62 41 100 43 43 59 59 70 12 27 43 43 27 27 27 24 43 43 62 43 70 29"
lista = [x for x in  map(int, x.split())]
```

Como pides una lista donde todos sean iguales (sin otra condición), arbitrariamente elijo el primer valor y formo el resultado copiando todos los valores iguales.

```
resultado = [x for x in lista if x == lista[0]]
```

Produciendo el resultado

```
[24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24]
```

La pregunta está mal planteada.